# The plug hasn't plug-in the socket

Tags: grammar

"The fan cann't on." he told me.

> "The plug hasn't plug in the socket."
>
> "The plug hasn't plug-in the socket."

I told him.

[image]

Which is the correct word? Plug in or plug-in?

Comment: The fan doesn't (*or* won't) turn on. ... It isn't plugged in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the right answer is :The plug hasn't been plugged in the socket.

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like there is only one way to say this. (That's **a** right answer, not **the** right answer.)